# Would it be OK to in-text cite a paper without mentioning the name and year explicitly in APA?

Tags: citations

For example, would this be allowed in APA:

Ohme, Reykowska, Wiener, and Choromanska (2009) showed...; in the next year, the same group of researchers conducted an experiment which also focused on ... to show...

Or do I have to add (Ohme, Reykowska, Wiener, & Choromanska, 2010) at the end of this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is covered in the [APA style blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/03/how-to-cite-direct-quotations.html). The example they give boils down to instead of using

> This idea was recently explored by Palladino and Wade (2010). Palladino and Wade’s (2010) results indicate that “a flexible mind is a healthy mind” (p. 147).

you can write:

> This idea was recently explored by Palladino and Wade (2010). They noted that "a flexible mind is a healthy mind" (Palladino & Wade, 2010, p. 147).

So yes, you need to give the full names and year of the reference in the body of the text.

Comment: On the other hand, without more context, the second reference could also be needed just for the page number of the quote.

Comment: @henning I am confused. In the first example, the parenthetical part only has a page number and the rest of the citation is in the text.

Comment: Hmm, the first example really supports your conclusion better than mine.

Comment: "instead of using ... you can ..." implies that the second option is optional and better. I would hesitate to say if it's better, but can clarify whether it's required?

Comment: @AzorAhai it is not required. The only thing APA requires is the full citation information in the sentence. Nominally the style manual lets you choose which you think is best, but copy editors may try and force their personal preferences on you.